# Jquery API value not working in input textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I am working in a crypto currency live price page. I am using Coingekho api for it. It is not working in
`$<input type="number" id="bitcoin" value=""/>` but it is woring in `<h2 id="bitcoin"></h2>`. I need it in `<input type="number" id="bitcoin" value=""/>`. Also I need all decimal value of price like $19755.25725.

```js
var btc = document.getElementById("bitcoin");
var ltc = document.getElementById("litecoin");
var eth = document.getElementById("ethereum");

var liveprice = {
  "async": true,
  "scroosDomain": true,
  "url": "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Clitecoin%2Cethereum&vs_currencies=usd",

  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {}
}

$.ajax(liveprice).done(function(response) {
  btc.innerHTML = response.bitcoin.usd;
  ltc.innerHTML = response.litecoin.usd;
  eth.innerHTML = response.ethereum.usd;

});
```

```html
    $<input type="number" id="bitcoin" value=""/>
    $<h2 id="litecoin"></h2>
    $<h2 id="ethereum"></h2>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Typo: `scroosDomain` should be `crossDomain`

Comment: "not working" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<input>` elements don't have `innerHTML`, since they're not containers. You need to set `btc.value`.

```js
var btc = document.getElementById("bitcoin");
var ltc = document.getElementById("litecoin");
var eth = document.getElementById("ethereum");

var liveprice = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Clitecoin%2Cethereum&vs_currencies=usd",

  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {}
}

$.ajax(liveprice).done(function(response) {
  btc.value = response.bitcoin.usd;
  ltc.innerHTML = response.litecoin.usd;
  eth.innerHTML = response.ethereum.usd;

});
```

```html
    $<input type="number" id="bitcoin" value=""/>
    $<h2 id="litecoin"></h2>
    $<h2 id="ethereum"></h2>
<script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

to change the value of the input tag you have to use `btc.value` instead of `btc.innerHTML`

```js
 btc.value = response.bitcoin.usd;
```